# Как открыть второе окно, поверх основного окна?

Tags: python, ооп, gui, pyqt, qdialog

При нажатии на *кнопку* у меня открывается *второе окно*. 
*Второе окно* появляется за основным и 
в него (второе окно) нельзя перейти, пока не закроется основное.

Как с этим бороться?

[image: Суть проблемы]

Comment: Вы забыли разместить пример демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Уже есть скриншот.

Comment: Скриншот это хорошо, но нужен минимальный пример демонстрации вашей проблемы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я не понимаю, какие у вас сложности составить минимальный пример?
В котором показать структуру вашего приложения, наследование, вызовы.
Не надо даже особо демонстрировать дизайн.

Попробую предположить, что первое ваше окно наследуется от `QtWidgets.QDialog`
и запускается как-то так `self.dialog.exec` и вы его не закрываете 
при нажатии на кнопку для открытия второго окно.

**QDialog::exec()**

Показывает диалог как модальный диалог, блокируя, пока пользователь не закроет его.

Если диалоговое окно является модальным приложения, 
пользователи не могут взаимодействовать с любым другим окном в том же приложении, 
пока они не закроют диалоговое окно. 
Если диалоговое окно является модальным окном, то при открытом диалоге блокируется 
только взаимодействие с родительским окном. 
По умолчанию диалог является модальным для приложения.

**Примечание**: избегайте использования этой функции; вместо этого используйте `open()`. 
В отличие от `exec()`, `open()` является асинхронным и не вращает дополнительный цикл событий. 
Это предотвращает появление ряда опасных ошибок 
(например, удаление родителя диалога, когда диалог открыт через exec()). 
При использовании open() вы можете подключиться к сигналу finish() QDialog, 
чтобы получать уведомления при закрытии диалога.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, root, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(root, **kwargs)
        self.main = root 
        label     = QtWidgets.QLabel('введите что нибудь')
        self.edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        button    = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Нажми чтобы отобразить')
        button.clicked.connect(self.push)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(label)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit)
        layout.addWidget(button)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def push(self):
        self.window2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()  #self
        self.window2.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.window2.label.resize(600, 400)
        self.window2.label.move(100, 100)
        self.window2.label.setText(self.edit.text())
        self.window2.label.show()

        self.main.label_main.setText(self.edit.text())
#        self.close()


class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.dialog = Dialog(self)

        layout          = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.label_main = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        button          = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Нажми')


# ваш вариант
#        button.clicked.connect(self.dialog.exec)          # <--- ---

# попробуйт так:        
        button.clicked.connect(self.dialog.open)           # <--- +++        
# или так:        
#        button.clicked.connect(self.dialog.show)          # <--- +++


        layout.addWidget(self.label_main)
        layout.addWidget(button)
        self.setLayout(layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app  = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()  
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]