# qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "windows" in ""

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, python-3.8

Cделал простой интерфейс и сделал из .ui файла .py файл. По идее он должен запустится и показать окно, но в консоли вылетает эта ошибка. Как это исправить? Использую PyQt 5, Python 3.8.2

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "windows" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

Comment: На ваши предыдущие вопросы есть ответы, но вы почему-то никак на это не реагируете? Если вы не знаете что надо сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Я не могу поменить коментарий как ответ.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/956173/pyqt-%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc